# RecyclerView passing value to fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview

How should I code this to pass my RecyclerView data to a fragment, and what code should I put in my fragment. This code works with activity, Ive seen solutions but I cant make then work for me. This code is from a adapter of a recyclerview

```
    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textNotifTitle= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNotifTitle);
        textNotifMessage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNotifMessage);
        TextDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Open the new activity (THIS WORKS)
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotifActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            Toast.makeText(context,"this is the position"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            bundle.putSerializable("DATA", data.get(getAdapterPosition()));


            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you have to change code :

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Open the new activity (THIS WORKS)
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotifActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            Toast.makeText(context,"this is the position"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            bundle.putSerializable("DATA", data.get(getAdapterPosition()));


            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            }
```

to

```
    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            Toast.makeText(context,"this is the position"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            bundle.putSerializable("DATA", data.get(getAdapterPosition()));
YourFragmentName f = new YourFragmentName();
f.setArguments(bundle);
   getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.your_container_frame_layout,
                f).commit();
            }
```

for passing any bundle to activity you have to putExtras function, but in Fragment you have to setArguments functions.

You can get the bundle in Fragment by below code:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       Bundle b = getArguments();
        if (b != null) {
            //todo your code
        }

    }
```